# Querying MongoDB, List all unique using GROUP BY and INNER JOIN in the same query

Tags: mongodb, group-by, inner-join

I'm doing a college job, but I'm not able to do these queries in the MongoDB database, I'll put the database links right down here for those who are kind enough to test, because I'm not getting it.

*Question: List all unique employees’ last and first names (using GROUP BY method) that have a current salary (i.e. to_date equals to 9999-01-01) greater than 90000, outputting both names in descending order (sort by the last name first and then the first name) and also displaying their current salaries (using the INNER JOIN method).*

I have tried some SQL conversions on Studio 3T, but I do not know what is wrong:

```
SELECT employees.emp_id, employees.first_name, employees.last_name, salaries.salary FROM employees
INNER JOIN salaries ON employees.emp_id = salaries.emp_id
WHERE to_date=9999-01-01 and salary > 90000
GROUP BY employees.emp_id
```

Some Data Employees:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157d9ba1b05372b2dacf6"), 
    "birth_date" : "1953-09-02", 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10001), 
    "first_name" : "Georgi", 
    "gender" : "M", 
    "hire_date" : "1986-06-26", 
    "last_name" : "Facello", 
    "email_address" : "gfacello@gmail.com"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157d9ba1b05372b2dacf7"), 
    "birth_date" : "1964-06-02", 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10002), 
    "first_name" : "Bezalel", 
    "gender" : "F", 
    "hire_date" : "1985-11-21", 
    "last_name" : "Simmel", 
    "email_address" : "fred.bloggs@company.ie"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157d9ba1b05372b2dacf8"), 
    "birth_date" : "1959-12-03", 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10003), 
    "first_name" : "Parto", 
    "gender" : "M", 
    "hire_date" : "1986-08-28", 
    "last_name" : "Bamford", 
    "email_address" : "fred.bloggs@company.ie"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157d9ba1b05372b2dacf9"), 
    "birth_date" : "1954-05-01", 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10004), 
    "first_name" : "Chirstian", 
    "gender" : "M", 
    "hire_date" : "1986-12-01", 
    "last_name" : "Koblick", 
    "email_address" : "fred.bloggs@company.ie"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157d9ba1b05372b2dacfa"), 
    "birth_date" : "1955-01-21", 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10005), 
    "first_name" : "Kyoichi", 
    "gender" : "M", 
    "hire_date" : "1989-09-12", 
    "last_name" : "Maliniak", 
    "email_address" : "fred.bloggs@company.ie"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157d9ba1b05372b2dacfb"), 
    "birth_date" : "1953-04-20", 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10006), 
    "first_name" : "Anneke", 
    "gender" : "F", 
    "hire_date" : "1989-06-02", 
    "last_name" : "Preusig", 
    "email_address" : "fred.bloggs@company.ie"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157d9ba1b05372b2dacfc"), 
    "birth_date" : "1957-05-23", 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10007), 
    "first_name" : "Tzvetan", 
    "gender" : "F", 
    "hire_date" : "1989-02-10", 
    "last_name" : "Zielinski", 
    "email_address" : "fred.bloggs@company.ie"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157d9ba1b05372b2dacfd"), 
    "birth_date" : "1958-02-19", 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10008), 
    "first_name" : "Saniya", 
    "gender" : "M", 
    "hire_date" : "1994-09-15", 
    "last_name" : "Kalloufi", 
    "email_address" : "fred.bloggs@company.ie"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157d9ba1b05372b2dacfe"), 
    "birth_date" : "1952-04-19", 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10009), 
    "first_name" : "Sumant", 
    "gender" : "F", 
    "hire_date" : "1985-02-18", 
    "last_name" : "Peac", 
    "email_address" : "fred.bloggs@company.ie"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157d9ba1b05372b2dacff"), 
    "birth_date" : "1963-06-01", 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10010), 
    "first_name" : "Duangkaew", 
    "gender" : "F", 
    "hire_date" : "1989-08-24", 
    "last_name" : "Piveteau", 
    "email_address" : "fred.bloggs@company.ie"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157d9ba1b05372b2dad00"), 
    "birth_date" : "1953-11-07", 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10011), 
    "first_name" : "Mary", 
    "gender" : "F", 
    "hire_date" : "1990-01-22", 
    "last_name" : "Sluis", 
    "email_address" : "fred.bloggs@company.ie"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157d9ba1b05372b2dad01"), 
    "birth_date" : "1960-10-04", 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10012), 
    "first_name" : "Patricio", 
    "gender" : "M", 
    "hire_date" : "1992-12-18", 
    "last_name" : "Bridgland", 
    "email_address" : "fred.bloggs@company.ie"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157d9ba1b05372b2dad02"), 
    "birth_date" : "1963-06-07", 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10013), 
    "first_name" : "Eberhardt", 
    "gender" : "M", 
    "hire_date" : "1985-10-20", 
    "last_name" : "Terkki", 
    "email_address" : "fred.bloggs@company.ie"
}
```

Some Salaries data:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157daba1b05372b2db050"), 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10001), 
    "from_date" : "1986-06-26", 
    "salary" : NumberInt(60117), 
    "to_date" : "1987-06-26"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157daba1b05372b2db052"), 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10001), 
    "from_date" : "1987-06-26", 
    "salary" : NumberInt(62102), 
    "to_date" : "1988-06-25"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157daba1b05372b2db054"), 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10001), 
    "from_date" : "1988-06-25", 
    "salary" : NumberInt(66074), 
    "to_date" : "1989-06-25"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157daba1b05372b2db056"), 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10001), 
    "from_date" : "1989-06-25", 
    "salary" : NumberInt(66596), 
    "to_date" : "1990-06-25"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157daba1b05372b2db058"), 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10001), 
    "from_date" : "1990-06-25", 
    "salary" : NumberInt(66961), 
    "to_date" : "1991-06-25"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157daba1b05372b2db059"), 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10001), 
    "from_date" : "1991-06-25", 
    "salary" : NumberInt(71046), 
    "to_date" : "1992-06-24"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157daba1b05372b2db05b"), 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10001), 
    "from_date" : "1992-06-24", 
    "salary" : NumberInt(74333), 
    "to_date" : "1993-06-24"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157daba1b05372b2db05d"), 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10001), 
    "from_date" : "1993-06-24", 
    "salary" : NumberInt(75286), 
    "to_date" : "1994-06-24"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157daba1b05372b2db05f"), 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10001), 
    "from_date" : "1994-06-24", 
    "salary" : NumberInt(75994), 
    "to_date" : "1995-06-24"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157daba1b05372b2db062"), 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10001), 
    "from_date" : "1995-06-24", 
    "salary" : NumberInt(76884), 
    "to_date" : "1996-06-23"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157daba1b05372b2db064"), 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10001), 
    "from_date" : "1996-06-23", 
    "salary" : NumberInt(80013), 
    "to_date" : "1997-06-23"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157daba1b05372b2db066"), 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10001), 
    "from_date" : "1997-06-23", 
    "salary" : NumberInt(81025), 
    "to_date" : "1998-06-23"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157daba1b05372b2db068"), 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10001), 
    "from_date" : "1998-06-23", 
    "salary" : NumberInt(81097), 
    "to_date" : "1999-06-23"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157daba1b05372b2db06a"), 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10001), 
    "from_date" : "1999-06-23", 
    "salary" : NumberInt(84917), 
    "to_date" : "2000-06-22"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157daba1b05372b2db06c"), 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10001), 
    "from_date" : "2000-06-22", 
    "salary" : NumberInt(85112), 
    "to_date" : "2001-06-22"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc157daba1b05372b2db06e"), 
    "emp_id" : NumberInt(10001), 
    "from_date" : "2001-06-22", 
    "salary" : NumberInt(85097), 
    "to_date" : "2002-06-22"
}
```

[Employees table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weEXP.png)

[Salaries table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWL46.png)

[MongoDbDump BSON files: employees.agz](https://gofile.io/d/7kxbBh)

Employees sample database (created by Fusheng Wang and Carlo Zaniolo
at Siemens Corporate Research)

Thanks

Comment: why dont you post the sample data instead of posting images and db?

Comment: I put the link of the sample after the images

Comment: We welcome you to stackoverflow. But this is not a way to put data, as a Image and whole db. You need to post the sample data instead of image and db

Comment: I agree adding a sample data is better

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `$project` and `$lookup`.

- `$project` to include or exclude the fields [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)
- `$lookup` to join collections. Here I have used [uncorrelated-sub-queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries). But there is a standard `$lookup` too

Here is the code

```
db.Employees.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 1,
      emp_id: 1,
      first_name: 1,
      last_name: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Salaries",
      let: { eId: "$emp_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: [ "$$eId", "$emp_id" ] },
                { $gt: [ "$salary", 80000 ] },
                { $eq: [ "$to_date", "2002-06-22" ] }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "salary"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3DrotOL5Sp4)**

Comment: I have tried here, but the salaries is not shown

Comment: Its showing in mongo playground for the given data. You can check the demo

Comment: it is shown all data, it does no matter the salary, with 80000 it is shown the salary just the first one even though there is only one bigger than 80000

Comment: Because the first one is only matching with the given data. You can directly see `emp_id`:10001 is only in salary in given data. So others dont get it. It makes sense, no!

Comment: But the question asked to show only who has the salary greater than 90000 or 80000 as you put there....

Comment: Does https://mongoplayground.net/p/XxxfwZ0AV-r this help you?

Comment: That is very weird, because in Mongodbpalyground is working, but my system keep executing like non stops, it just stops when I push the stop button and it does not give any result